# eslint error Expected indentation of 1 tab character but found 0

Tags: intellij-idea, eslint, eslintrc

I'm working on a project that has a eslintrc file and when I run npm run test in my Intellij project. I get an error

```
Expected indentation of 1 tab character but found 0
```

I tried checking the box for enable ESlint search for .eslintrc 
file > other settings > default settings > Languages & Frameworks > javascript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react",
    "flow-vars"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      "\\.(html|json|properties)$",
      "DevTools"
    ],
    "import/resolver": {
      "webpack": {
        "config": "./src/js/webpack/webpack.base.config.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "eqeqeq": [2, "allow-null"],
    "flow-vars/define-flow-type": 1,
    "flow-vars/use-flow-type": 1,
    "func-names": 0,
    "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
    "indent": [2, "tab", {"SwitchCase": 1}],
    "new-cap": 0,
    "no-multi-spaces": [2, {"exceptions": {"VariableDeclarator": true}}],
    "no-param-reassign": [2, {"props": false}],
    "no-script-url": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": [2, {"args": "after-used", "argsIgnorePattern": "^_"}],
    "no-use-before-define": [2, "nofunc"],
    "quote-props": [2, "consistent-as-needed"],
    "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, "tab"],
    "react/jsx-no-bind": [2, {
      "ignoreRefs": false,
      "allowArrowFunctions": false,
      "allowBind": false
    }],
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "spaced-comment": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "__ENV__": false,
    "__DEV__": false,
    "__TEST__": false
  }
}
```

I even tried just changing the tab number to 2 from 4 in settings but get the error. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the linting error should indicate the file & line number of where it originated from.

In this case, you can try running the following command: `eslint --fix` & allow eslint to fix that indentation error for you.

Comment: Where would I put eslint --fix in intellij

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Intellij, are you able to access your project folder via the terminal & run the command?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone having this issue the only way I could solve it was to uncheck the option Enable EditorConfig support in intellij.

```
preferences >  Code Style > EditorConfig
```